# Is there a technique to execute evil maid for other OSs, that is equivalent to the simplicity of EvilAbigail

Tags: windows

I was recently looking at [EvilAbigail](https://github.com/AonCyberLabs/EvilAbigail) and making sad faces over how vulnerable my Linux FDE system is, when I started to wonder if there was a similar simple attack for other OSs. I did a bunch of searching but couldn't even find any information on the current state-of-the-art for evil maid on other OSs, let alone a skiddy friendly click-to-own script/technique.

I'm not particularly talking about harder cases either, like with TPM support for root of trust. No, even seemingly trivial scenarios don't appear to have publicly available exploits.

I can't imagine default setting in OSs that have a track record for being exploitable could possibly be inherently better at anti evil maid than carefully set up GNU/Linux system. So, I wonder, what is the reason for me not finding much in the way of publicized attacks of that nature? Is there actually such a thing for other OSs?

Comment: This is why *secure boot* exists. Without secure boot it's possible on any OS as the boot process runs before the OS.

Comment: I am aware of Secure Boot, I actually had it in my original question, but I more or less had to remove it for bureaucratic reasons. Putting that aside, I don't see anything that is click-to-own for any system other than GNU/Linux with EvilAbigail. That is even for trivial cases without TPM support (Secure Boot work-alikes.)